# Construct JSONArray with JSONObjects Dynamically Android

Tags: java, android

for short:

```
Input =>  1001,1002,1003...n
Desired output => "recipients":[{"@id":"1001"},{"@id":"1002"},{"@id":"1003"},...n]
```

How can i convert the input into the desired JSONArray output.

i started with

```
try {
    JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject vm = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject content = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject content1 = new JSONObject();

    vm.put("@id", "10000");
    content.put("@id","10001");
    content1.put("@id","10002");

    mainArray.put(",");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but i am not on the light way. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this code

```
try {
    int[] ids = { 100, 200, 300 };
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray recipients = new JSONArray();
    for (int id : ids) {
        JSONObject idsJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        idsJsonObject.put("@id", id);
        recipients.put(idsJsonObject);
    }
    mainObject.put("recipients", recipients);
    System.out.println(mainObject.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```